# Sort HTML Select by partial text

Tags: javascript, sorting, select, text, partial

I need to sort the items by parts of the text based on hyphens in the text.
For Example:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Oranges - Box A - Deliver</option>
    <option value="2">Apples - Box A - Deliver</option>
    <option value="3">Bananas - Box B - Deliver</option>
</select>
```

I need to sort the items based on the text after the first hyphen, then sort by the beginning text up to the first hyphen.

The sorted result would look like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="2">Apples - Box A - Deliver</option>
    <option value="1">Oranges - Box A - Deliver</option>
    <option value="3">Bananas - Box B - Deliver</option>
</select>
```

So, it needs to be sorted by the Box name, then by the Fruit.
I'm using the following sort, but it uses the whole text.

```
function sortAllItems(listname) {
    var $r = $(listname + " option");
    $r.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a.text).localeCompare(b.text);
    });
    $(listname).append($($r));
}
```

I'm sure there is some slick way to find the hyphens and substring stuff together, but I haven't been able to come up with something that works.

Has anyone had to do something crazy like this before?  I appreciate your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following *callback*:

```
function (a, b) {
   return (a.text.split('-')[1]+a.text).localeCompare(b.text.split('-')[1]+b.text);
}
```

It's based on the evidence that, if you sort sort a list alphabetically and the same word appears several times in different position, only the first one will have effect.

So:

```
Box A - Oranges - Box A - Deliver
Box A - Apples - Box A - Deliver
Box B - Bananas - Box B - Deliver
```

Will be sort the same way as:

```
Box A - Oranges - Deliver
Box A - Apples - Deliver
Box B - Bananas - Deliver
```

I repeat the concept once again, if the same word appears on several position, only the first matters.

Comment: Brilliant!  This works PERFECTLY!  I totally forgot about split()! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate sort on sub parts should work:

```
$r.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.text.split(" - ")[1]).localeCompare(b.text.split(" - ")[1]);
});

$r.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.text.split(" - ")[0]).localeCompare(b.text.split(" - ")[0]);
});
```

Comment: this would work as well!  But, I would prefer to just do one sort as opposed two.  I believe one sort, as shown above by ChristianTraina, would be more efficient.  Thanks for replying with your idea!